# Updating part of the title tag, but not all of it, or at least a good work around?

Tags: jquery, html, notifications, title

I want to have the number of notifications in the title part of (like Facebook does), however I haven't been able to come up with a good way of doing this. I did this a few years ago, but the way I did it wasn't that good, it would mess up and remove wrong parts of it sometime. So I'm trying to come up with the easiest way to do this.

and the value of the title is dynamic, so I can't just have it manually do it one way.

So like:

(8) MySite - Home Page

then when it changes it would just go like:
MySite - Home Page OR MySite - UserID102

What I had done before is this:

```
    var got_title = $('title').html();
    var find_notifications = got_title.match(/\([0-9]\)\s/); ///look for (1-9)

    if(find_notifications)
     {
      var default_title = got_title.split(' ')[1];
     }
     if(!find_notifications)
     {
     var default_title = got_title;
     }
     $('title').html(update_notification+default_title);
```

However it's very unreliable, sometimes it worked fine, but sometimes it would keep adding notifications, like:

MySite - Home --> (5) MySite - Home --> (5)(5)(5)(5)(5)(5) MySite - Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the content of `update_notification`, but maybe this can help you:

```
var got_title = $('title').html();
var default_title = got_title.match(/(\(\d+\)\s)?(.*)/)[2];
$('title').html(update_notification+default_title);
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/U2sKr/1/).

Comment: If I remember correctly "update_notification" is (1)  or whatever the number of notifications may be

Comment: The `update_notification` has the new number of notifications?

Comment: Yes, your example loosk like it works as I want it to. I'll give it a go, thanks.